# Synchronize windows folders

Tags: windows, powershell, eclipse-plugin

I have set up remote sync in my eclipse to copy jsp and js files at different locations. I am observing that sometimes because of this sync (I need to keep build auto option enabled) eclipse is hanging and I need to kill the process.In windows do we have any option to sync two local folders. I searched but options I am getting through third party software. I am using my office laptop, so don't want to use any third party software and want to check if windows provide any easy option for that.

I miss unix and rsync :(

---

Currently I am using a bat file to copy these files. I think robocopy is a good option too.

xcopy /s /d /y source folder destination foler

Comment: `rsync` is named [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, let me check on robocopy. For time being I am using xcopy.

Comment: robocopy >>>>>>> xcopy (full name is Robust File Copy :-) )

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Rsync is NOT called Robocopy on Windows. Rsync is a Linux solution only available on Windows trough Cygwin or WSL. Even though Robocopy is better than Xcopy or regular copy, it supports entirely different features than Rsync.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a useful little program in Windows called `robocopy` that ships with Win7 and above.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

```
robocopy <source> <destination> /mir /copyall
```

This is what you can use to copy a source directory to a target directory including all subdirectories, files, and metadata. It's uni-directional so won't check both ways, but there are time and change based triggers you can set with a windows startup task so you can make the folders auto-sync as you work.

If you read the link, you'll find the `/mot:` and `/mon:` flags which will watch the folders for changes/wait a certain amount of time then copy again.

In addition, it is really good at logging output, and is excellent when used as a system startup process.

Comment: +1 for mentioning /mot: and /mon: flag. I am using xcopy now and added this script to eclipse, so after every change I run it. let me look to robocopy as well.

Comment: robocopy is amazing and can do net share transfers at blinding speeds.