# How to: Write a Powershell Script to move files when saves are detected

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015

If this is the wrong place for this question, please let me know, and I'll move it

In doing development on my machine, I work in Visual Studio 2015. I have a development directory for my project, and whenever I do a build, everything goes into a Build directory, which I have attached to IIS for testing the code.

I'd like to know how to write a shell script that will detect any saved files (of specific extension types) in the solution folder, and if detected - copy those files with overwrite to the build directory.

Basically, an automatic sync of files that don't require a compile to update: .htm, .html, .aspx, .json, .js, .css, .png, .jpg, .gif, etc.

The reasoning: The solution I'm working in is... Large. And doing a full build means my refresh on my site takes longer, as it has to do an `IISRESET`. When the file I'm updating isn't a .cs, there's no need to recompile the dlls, and if the file were just copied, I could simply refresh the page and see my changes right away.

Comment: It would make more sense to use gulp to do this given that they've started supporting it in VS2013+. You'd create a gulp task to copy them over and add a gulp.watch on project start

Comment: I think I answered a question very similar to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407166/synchronize-windows-folders/36407584#36407584